# Почему метод вызывается раньше окончания resolve и так много раз?

Tags: angular2

Есть такой resolve:

```
export class PermissionResolver implements Resolve<any> {
     constructor(private authService: AuthorizationService, private permissionService: PermissionService) { }

     resolve(
          route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
          state: RouterStateSnapshot
     ): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
          return this.authService.authorize().pipe(tap(() => {
               this.permissionService.currentUser = this.authService.currentUser;
          }));
     }
}
```

Подцеплен к маршруту так:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full', resolve: { data: PermissionResolver }
  }
];
```

Так вот меня беспокоит следующее:

1) Когда точка останова оставливается тут `this.permissionService.currentUser=this.authService.currentUser`, то консоль уже пестрит ошибками об `undefined`, так как `currentUser` используется в биндинге и меню сайта так же отображается.

Если верить документации, то страница не должна грузится пока не отработает resolve.

2)Этот сервис биндится в компоненте:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" [ngClass]="{'disabled':!permissionService.canView()}"
```

, как я уже говорил, консоль пестрит ошибками. А когда ошибки проходят, то в консоли отображается 10-ок сообщений об успешном вызове метода(я логирую этот метод).

Почему так происходит?

Comment: у тебя просто проблемы с асинхронностью, я видел ты делаешь подписки там где не надо еще в предыдущих вопросах, так что может быть из-за этого :) если плохо понимаешь конструкции rxjs то конвертируй потоки в промис через `toPromise` и работай уже с async/await

Comment: @overthesanity да не, я взял код, который ты мне привел в примере. Я так же перепроверил все места, где может дергаться данный метод и он дергается только в этом компоненте => я не понимаю, почему так происходит=(

Comment: а этот `li` находится в `HomeComponent`?

Comment: @overthesanity, ну как сказать... HomeComponent состоит из 2-ух компонентов: nav-menu и router-outlet

Comment: @overthesanity, а сам li находится в компоненте nav-menu. Никаких подписок нету кроме ресолвера.

Comment: мне сложно так сказать, сделай пример на stackblitz с логикой похожей на твою

Comment: @overthesanity, стоп стоп стоп. Я немного наврал. Менюха находится внутри app.component. Это не может быть причиной того, что она грузится до резолва?

Comment: да, это и есть причина

Comment: @overthesanity т.е в app.component оставить только router-outlet, а менюху переместить в контейнер, где будет <nav-menu> и router-outlet ?

Comment: да, то что я написал выше сработало и теперь нету ругани на неопределенность.

Comment: @overthesanity, похоже, что мультивызов привязок-это нормально https://stackoverflow.com/a/26993212/4244707

Comment: >  `что мультивызов привязок-это нормально` - я думал вопрос о резолверах ))

Answer (score 0):

1)С горем по полам, выяснил, что проблема была связана с тем, что менюха находилась в app.component=> грузилась до всех резолверов...

Я вынес этот код:

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class="sticky-top">
    <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
  </div>
  <div class="body-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

В отдельный компонент, допустим base.component, а в app.component оставил только router-outlet.

Далее я переписал маршруты так:

Корневой модуль:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full', resolve: { data: PermissionResolver }
  }
];
```

HomeComponent:

```
    const homeRoutes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'home', component: AssemblyContainerComponent, children: [
          {
            path: '', component: AssemblyHomeComponent
          },
//какие-то дочерние маршруты
```

AboutComponent:

```
    const aboutRoutes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'about', component: aboutComponent
      }
    ];
//какие-то дочерние маршруты
```

В

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: BaseComponent, resolve: { data: PermissionResolver }, children: [
      {
        path: '', loadChildren: './area/Home/Home.module#HomeModule',
      },
      {
        path: 'about', loadChildren: './area/about/about.module#aboutModule',
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

HomeComponent:

```
    const homeRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'home', component: HomeContainerComponent, children: [
          {
            path: '', component: AssemblyHomeComponent
          },
//какие-то дочерние маршруты
```

AboutComponent:

```
    const aboutRoutes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '', component: aboutComponent
      }
    ];
//какие-то дочерние маршруты
```

P.S Пните в комментах, если это делается как-то по другому.

2)Если верить вот [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26993212/4244707) ответу на enSO, то это нормально, так как Angular использует "грязную" проверку, что бы синхронизировать изменения.